# Can I customize an excel chart to read data and formatting input from a table

Tags: excel, charts

I'd like to be able to create an excel chart that looks something like this:

[image]

Where I have an excel table that contains all the data and formatting input. something like this:

[image]

My goal is to create such charts every two weeks, where the color and the shape of the marker represents different things. Color represents if a particular project has been completed, in progress, not yet started. Shape represents who is responsible.

My goal is to update the dates, step details, marker color, marker shape, output position (so it's readable) etc by changing the numbers in my source table and then refresh the chart.

The above picture and table is from a sample I found on the internet but I am unable to decipher all the different options that the series function has and how I can also tell it what the marker shape and fill can be from a table. I don't want to have to individually right click on each point and have to customize it.

This is the function used in the file:

```
=SERIES('Project Timeline'!$D$20,'Project Timeline'!$C$21:$C$31,'Project Timeline'!$D$21:$D$33,2)
```

Attached is the file that I am working on. I haven't gotten very far. All the color changes that I have made have been by hand. I am scouring the net but any help or guidance I get here will be greatly appreciated.

Link to file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4tcwo2ZvQCRMkhLSThwRjhRM28/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking.  What should change to make the other aspects change?

If it's stuff in the same sheet there, you can use if statements, or nested if statements to make the changes.

For example, if you want marker shape to be defined by the position, and position is column C, column F could be:

```
=if(B1<0,"Square",if(B1<10,"Oval",if(B1<=15,"Rectangle","Circle")))
```

Which would make values less than 0 squares, less than 10 ovals, less than or equal to 15 rectangles, and everything else (GT 15) Circles.

Comment: I don't know how to get my "Series" command to read the information in Column F. Suppose I write your code in Column F and F2 contains the string "Circle" , how do I get the "Series" command to understand that it's meant to be the marker shape for the first point on the axes?

Comment: I am unable to find the detailed syntax of the "Series" command, so I can feed in (via a table) every aspect of the chart generation to it.

Comment: Aah, that gets a lot more complicated, if the chart isn't receiving those columns as inputs.  Here's a VBA article about programatically creating charts that sets some variables, but that's a whole other realm of work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg980940(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: If you set up a chart the way you'd like (assuming your parameters will be the same each time) you can copy and paste the chart and then just change the series to point to the new cells (even across workbooks).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd be happy to write a VBA code to do the same. I need to flexibility because project status might change. A project that hadn't started (color brown) may have been completed (color greeen). A project that was being done by a particular team might now be done by someone else (change in shape),  and as we move along the timeline the objectives may change also. I don't want to manually tinker this in the chart. I wanna make changes in a table and let the chart reflect it with the click of a button.